# Is it possible to copy a single column with data in a table to another table in the same schema?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to copy a single column with data in a table to another table in the same schema?

I used:

INSERT INTO Emp1
SELECT department_id FROM employees;

I get this error: Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: I'm guessing Emp1 has more than 1 column. Specify the column in which to insert department_id.

Comment: Error is very clear.Unless you specify a column to be inserted to you have to provide values for all columns..

Answer (score 0):

Your INSERT is fine but you missed a column name to insert to:

```
INSERT INTO Emp1 (column_to_insert) SELECT department_id FROM employees;
```

It works fine provided ALL other columns in Emp1 either **allow NULL** or have **default values** or **autoincrement**.